# Cant install Blackberry SDK from Momentics

Tags: mobile, titanium, blackberry-10

I'm trying to download the Blackberry SDK from 2 days using their IDE (because it is the only way to get their SDK?), and now I got an error:

```
There was an error updating SDK. Press the Details button to review the error.
SDK Install or Update Operation operation failed: An error occurred while installing the items
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile,phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]bbndk.win32.cshost.10.2.0.1155 1.0.0, action=com.qnx.tools.ide.sdk.manager.core.actions.SdkManagerInstallAction).
error in opening zip file
error in opening zip file
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null -->  [R]bbndk.win32.cshost.10.2.0.1155 1.0.0,  action=com.qnx.tools.ide.sdk.manager.core.actions.SdkManagerInstallAction).
error in opening zip file
error in opening zip file
```

and this happened even when it finishs downloading:

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

So I understand you want to install the blackberry SDK for Titanium?

If that is the case, you should download the Blackberry SDK here:

http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/bb/

Else, if you want the Native SKD, or CAscades SDK, you must then download it through Momentics.

Comment: the native sdk only comes using the Momentics, and this is what caused problems :(
`Use the Momentics IDE to download the BlackBerry 10 Native SDK, and get ahold of all the tools and libraries that you need for developing an application for BlackBerry 10`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Close BlackBerry Momentics.
2. Delete the **host_xxx** and **target_xxx** folders inside BlackBerry Momentics installation folder that correspond to the BlackBerry Native SDK version that is failing to install.
3. Delete all the contents of the **p2** folder inside BlackBerry Momentics installation folder.
4. Launch BlackBerry Momentics and try to install again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Just try to uninstall and re-install the momentics IDE then go for sdk download ..